# Removing first two digits in year field using Jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, angularjs, substring

I'm going to list all the years ahead of 2018 to one drop down using angular js. Currently, I'm doing a payment gateway enhancement, and there I want to give to the user to select the year according to there credit card.

I used

```
$scope.years = Enumerable.Range(new Date().getFullYear(), 36, 1).ToArray();
```

and this will gives all the years ahead starting from 2018 to 2054. But the case is when it comes to an array I don't need to display the year in 4 digits way. I want to display it like 18, 19, 20, and so on. currently, I'm getting the value like 2018, 2019, 2020.

My main concern is how to remove the first two digits when it comes to the array.

I used the substring() but its only work for the first item only in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$scope.years = Enumerable.Range(Number(new Date().getFullYear().toString().substr(2, 4)), 36, 1).ToArray();
```

Comment: This is much helpfull, and on the spot. i was trying to use jquery map function and use iteratively by using foreach . Thanks a lot for the simplest code piece.

Comment: You're welcome, just mark it as solved to help others ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this using for loop :

```
$scope.years= [2018,2019,2020]; //just an example
for (var i=0; i<$scope.years.length; i++){
    $scope.years[i] = parseInt($scope.years[i].toString().substring(2,4));
}
```

output :

> [18,19,20]

Comment: I think the below code piece would be the best answer. I tried the same way as you mentioned by using a loop. but @Talavera code piece on the spot. Thanks for the push mate.

Comment: $scope.years = Enumerable.Range(Number(new Date().getFullYear().toString().substr(2, 4)), 36, 1).ToArray();